# Steam Auth $steamid not able to use in routes in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

Im trying to use steamid as my route so it will be www.example.com./profile/76561198050605019

The code i have right now is:

```
Route::get('{steamid}', function($steamid){
    $user = App\user::find($steamid);
    echo 'hello my steam name is ' . $user->username . '<br />';
    echo 'hello my steam ID64 is ' . $user->steamid . '<br />';
});
```

I have that and that should work but its not.
I have tryed this and it works:

```
Route::get('{steamid}', function($id){
    $user = App\user::find($id);
    echo 'hello my steam name is ' . $user->username . '<br />';
});
```

With the url of www.example.com/profile/3

EDIT::

I have fixed my own problem

```
$user = User::where('steamid', $steamid)->firstOrFail();
```

I need to use that line.

Comment: What's not working, what's the error?

Comment: Well the error is that the url with the steam id is not working. But i know now why its not working and i have fixed it

Comment: Could you also post your solution as an answer, and accept it so that it will be obvious for other people to see what the solution is?

Comment: Yeah I will sorry, I'm new to stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the problem you need to change this

```
$user = App\user::find($steamid);
```

This

```
$user = App\user::where('steamid', $steamid)->firstOrFail();
```